# Checking for specific character in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to check a string in a batch file to make sure it doesn't include any of the following characters: /:*?"<>|

I don't know whether it would be easier to check to see if it contains valid characters, as the batch file might fail with there being the above characters in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

double quotes are difficult to handle in batch and I didn't add it.
If a double quotes exists in the `string` variable then this can fail too.

```
@echo off
set "string=1234abcd"
for /f "delims=/:*?<>|" %%a in ("%string%") do if "%%a"=="%string%" echo characters were not found
pause
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Not having the double quotes isn't a problem because it closes the batch window when it's typed in. In this instance, I can't see any reason why many of these characters would be typed in, it's just a precautionary measure in case they ever are typed in.